# Manage SharePoint Permissions with remote ASP.NET Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, asp.net, acs

We have the following requirements and I have my doubts if this is possible to implement.

- Application is a standalone ASP.NET application with its own SQL Data source
- Application should manage permissions across Farms, Site Collections, Subsites, Libraries/Lists & Library/List items levels
- There are multiple farms of 2010 on-prem, 2013 on-prem & O365. Application should manage all of them
- There are multiple sub-domains and most probably certificates too might be different
- Application should have Auditing & Reporting capabilities

While I believe this is possible to implement, the biggest pain points might be the following, do you agree?

- Claims provider for all 3 environments (2010, 2013 & O365) should be different and can't be same. I was thinking C2WTS.
- Performance with 200,000 users and each site collection having 100+ subsites & each farm having 25+ site collections would be very bad
- Also, external user's might be accessing these SP Sites